# Why refs() a object will always return 65535 in R?

Tags: r, memory-address

I try to implement the example in  [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification) to see how many names point to a location. As the author said

> Note that if you’re using RStudio, `refs()` will always return 2: the environment browser makes a reference to every object you create on the command line.

However, for my case, `refs()` will always return `65535`, even I had cleared the global environment

```r
library(pryr)
x <- 1:10
c(address(x), refs(x))

## "0x1d931f32d68" "65535"
```

What does this mean?

Comment: 16 bit integer: 65535 is -1 so maybe it indicates an error

Comment: @Ben Bolker, did you check the [ref](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/12/lobstr/) function from `lobstr`?

Comment: Yes; it doesn't seem to do the same thing as `pryr::refs()`, at least as far as I could tell from a quick glance/experiment. (I am very curious why `refs()` appears to be broken/wrong now -- changes in R internals? -- but it was too much work to dig in and try to figure it out, which is part of why I offered the bounty ...)

Answer (score 6):

[`refs` uses](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/src/inspect.cpp#L167) the [`named` field](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header) of a `SEXP` to determine the number of references. This in itself is already not very precise, as originally it could only take the values 0, 1 or 2. [Also, the `NAMED` procedure to count the references can lead to confusion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507382/r3-4-viewing-object-reference-counts-named)

At some point, there was a change in the SEXP header so that the `named` field can take more bits. If I understand the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header) correctly, this was with R 3.5.0. Currently, the standard for `NAMED_BITS` is 16 - leading to a maximum of 65535 for the `named` field.

Another change with R 3.5.0 was the [`ALTREP` project](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/ALTREP/ALTREP.html). This leads to a more efficient representation of basic R objects. One of this representation are [compact integer vectors](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/ALTREP/ALTREP.html#compact_integer_vectors). Basically, integer vectors that don't have a gap (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4` and not `1, 3, 4`) are represented only by their start and end value. However, these "compact" representations are marked as [non mutable](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/altclasses.c#L335). This is achieved by assigning [`NAMEDMAX` or `REFCNTMAX`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Defn.h#L252) - which is 65535.

This is only the case if you use `:` or `seq` (with dispatch to `seq.int`):

```
library(pryr)
x <- 1:10
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @0x00000000156ecce8 13 INTSXP g0c0 [REF(65535)]  1 : 10 (compact)
refs(x)
# [1] 65535
```

and

```
y <- seq(1, 10)
# @0x000000000521e218 13 INTSXP g0c0 [REF(65535)]  1 : 10 (compact)
refs(y)
# [1] 65535
```

Here, you can see the reference count ([`REF` field because with R 4.0.0, there was a change away from the `NAMED` procedure to reference counting](https://developer.r-project.org/Refcnt.html)) and that the vector is represented in the compact form.

When initialising the vector in a naive way, then the normal representation is used and the reference count is 1:

```
z <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)
# @0x00000000057c7808 13 INTSXP g0c4 [REF(1)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
refs(z)
# [1] 1
```

With R 4.1.3 in a console, not in RStudio.